# Python loop ask

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Can someone help me how do i display both food and drink if i answered yes?

example:

choose:1

you have entered food

Do you want to select another?(Y/N):y

choose:2

Do you want to select another?(Y/N):n

selected:

food

drink

thanks in advance

```
    answer="Y"
    while(answer=="Y"):       
      print("1-food")
      print("2-drink")
      opt=int(input("Choose:"))`
      if(opt==1):` 
          print("You have selected food")
      if(op==2):
          print("You have selected drink"):
     answer=input("Do you want to select another?(Y/N)").upper()
```

Comment: Do you mean a `print("3-both")` and `if(opt==3): print("You have selected food and drink")`? By the way, you have `op==2` rather than `opt==2`.

Comment: It may just be a problem with the copy-pasting to StackOverflow, but your last line is not correctly indented.

Comment: Let's first look a bit more at how the program of this assignment is supposed to work. With these questions you could never select that you don't want food anymore or don't want drinks anymore. Shouldn't it be so that both questions are asked one after another (Food?, then Drink?) and that you both can answer them with yes or no. In that way you could also leave out the food or drink again. Or is your interpretation of the assignment really correct.

Comment: You have to store selected item in variable or list and once user says "N" it should print items in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
food = False
drink = False    
answer="Y"
    while(answer=="Y"):       
      print("1-food")
      print("2-drink")
      opt=int(input("Choose:"))
      if(opt==1): 
          print("You have selected food")
          food = True
      if(op==2):
          print("You have selected drink"):
          drink = True
     answer=input("Do you want to select another?(Y/N)").upper()
if food: print "food"
if drink: print "drink"
```

All you need to do is add two variables `food` and `drink` and if you selected the relevant option then you set it to `True`. Then at the end of your `while` loop you simply test to see if they are set.